# Why box-sizing property act like this?

Tags: html, css

I want to create a 3x3 layout. I apply box-sizing: border-box to all the elements. It's pretty simple, but when I add borders on parent and child divs, the layout breaks.

```
html{
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
*{
   box-sizing: inherit;
}
.box{
      width: 300px;
      height: 300px;
      margin: 50px auto;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }
    .inner-box{
      height: 100px;
      width: 100px;
      background: cadetblue;
      border: 1px solid red;
      box-sizing: border-box;  
      float: left;
    }
```

[Before I comment HTML and *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EErn4.png)

So to make it works, I have to comment styles for HTML and *. After that, the layout looks like this:
[After I comment HTML and *](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3TYa.png)

I know I can set width on child elements to be calc(100%/3), but in that case, the width of child elements will be less than 100px. I'm curious why this happening and am I making some mistakes?

here is the HTML :

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
    <div class="inner-box"></div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Please could you show the HTML. And why are you using float? grid or flex might suit your requirement.

Comment: 300px including 2px of borders means that you have less than 300px for the childs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using box-sizing: border-box, the outside box has an overall width of 300px - including its borders.

Hence there isn't quite enough space to get the third element in.

If you put the box-sizing of the outer box back to content then there is space:

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

* {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

.inner-box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: cadetblue;
  border: 1px solid red;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="inner-box"></div>
  <div class="inner-box"></div>
  <div class="inner-box"></div>
  <div class="inner-box"></div>
  <div class="inner-box"></div>
  <div class="inner-box"></div>
  <div class="inner-box"></div>
  <div class="inner-box"></div>
  <div class="inner-box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @A Haworth      Thanks for the explanation!